# Why isn't my @BeforeClass method running?

Tags: java, junit, annotations

I have the following code:

```
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpOnce() throws InterruptedException {
        fail("LOL");
    }
```

And various other methods that are either @Before, @After, @Test or @AfterClass methods.

The test doesn't fail on start up as it seems it should. Can someone help me please?

I have JUnit 4.5

The method is failing in an immediate call to setUp() which is annotated as @before.
Class def is :

```
public class myTests extends TestCase {
```

Comment: Can you confirm what version of junit you have in your classpath?

Comment: I have JUnit 4.5 in classpath

Answer (score 73, accepted):

do NOT extend TestCase AND use annotations at the same time!
If you need to create a test suite with annotations, use the RunWith annotation like:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({ MyTests.class, OtherTest.class })
public class AllTests {
    // empty
}


public class MyTests {  // no extends here
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpOnce() throws InterruptedException {
        ...
    @Test
    ...
```

*(by convention: class names with uppercase letter)*

Comment: Yes this is a better option. Didn't know about these @Suite and @RunWith annotations. +1 and thanks for your inputs.

Comment: thanks. I had a hard time to find it last week.. kind of just in time

Comment: Thank you Carlos, works fine now. Also thanks for all your help Vinegar.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger i'm extending a class which has methods like `logins`  and `sessions` and I need to run @BeforeClass annotated method also. Is that possible?

Comment: @yashhy - sorry, this should be asked as a question, not as a comment.

Comment: @yashhy 4 years late but for the other readers, yes that's possible.

Answer (score 22):

Make sure you imported @Test from the correct package.

- Correct package: org.junit.Test
- Incorrect pacakge: org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

Please note that this is a solution for: If your @Before, @Atter, etc did not get called at all.

Answer (score 17):

the method [must be static](http://junit.org/junit/javadoc/4.5/org/junit/BeforeClass.html) and not directly call fail (otherwise the other methods won't be executed).

The following class shows all the standard JUnit 4 method types:

```
public class Sample {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() {
        System.out.println("@BeforeClass");
    }

    @Before
    public void before() {
        System.out.println("@Before");
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("@Test");
    }

    @After
    public void after() {
        System.out.println("@After");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void afterClass() {
        System.out.println("@AfterClass");
    }

}
```

and the ouput is (not surprisingly):

```
@BeforeClass
@Before
@Test
@After
@AfterClass
```

Comment: You are correct, thanks, but did not start working once i changed to static.

Comment: Show us the class definition. It might be the case that your class is a subclass of someother, and that parent class may have some method annotated as @BeforeClass, and that method of the parent class is ending up with some errors and causing the halt.

Comment: Otherwise, try to add a normal test method.

Comment: The method is failing in an immediate call to setUp() which is annotated as @before.
Class def is :
public class myTests extends TestCase {

Comment: Are you having any @Test methods?

Comment: It doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that :

- Your test class doesn't inherits from TestCase
- The @BeforeClass method is static
- You don't have more than one @BeforeClass method in test class hierarchy (only the most specialized @BeforeClass method will be executed)

Comment: Running jUnit 4.11 allows more than one @BeforeClass , one in your class and one in a super class,  and calls both.

Answer (score 2):

Check your imports.

- @Before
- @After
- @BeforeClass (this should be static)
- @AfterClass  (this should be static)

and @Test annotations should import from same path.

Answer (score 0):

In order that the before annotated function will run , I had to do the following:
If you use Maven , add a dependency to Junit 4.11+:

```
      <properties>
              <version.java>1.7</version.java>
              <version.log4j>1.2.13</version.log4j>
              <version.mockito>1.9.0</version.mockito>
              <version.power-mockito>1.4.12</version.power-mockito>
               <version.junit>4.11</version.junit>   
              <version.power-mockito>1.4.12</version.power-mockito>
      </properties>
```

and the dependency:

```
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
         <groupId>junit</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
         <version>${version.junit}</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>    
        .
        .
        .
      </dependencies>
```

Make sure your Junit Test class is not extending The TestCase class, since this will cause overlapping with Older version:

```
public class TuxedoExceptionMapperTest{
   protected TuxedoExceptionMapper subject;

   @Before
   public void before() throws Exception {
     subject = TuxedoExceptionMapper.getInstance();
      System.out.println("Start");
      MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Things to check:

- Junit package is: org.junit.Test
- You don't have a static block. (I learned it the hard way)