# Why isn't @Before being called

Tags: java, junit

In the following test class my test object doesn't get initialised because Before isn't being called.

Any ideas?

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class CalcDateToolTest extends TestCase 
{
    DatesCalculator calc;

    @Before
    public void initialize() {
        System.out.println("Before");
        calc = new DatesCalculator("15/06/2013", "30/06/2013");
    }

    @Test
    public void testCalcDayDiff() {
        assertEquals(true, calc.getFromDate());
    }

    @After
    public void destroy() {
        calc = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you remove your old post? I was right at that moment posting a comment for a related question... There might be an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/733358/1993402. The conclusion of that: `do NOT extend TestCase AND use annotations at the same time!`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why isn't my @BeforeClass method running?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733037/why-isnt-my-beforeclass-method-running)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `extends TestCase` from your code.

Eg :

```
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class CalcDateToolTest {
    DatesCalculator calc;

    @Before
    public void initialize() {
        System.out.println("Before");
        calc = new DatesCalculator("15/06/2013", "30/06/2013");
    }

    @Test
    public void testCalcDayDiff() {
        assertEquals(true, calc.getFromDate());
    }

    @After
    public void destroy() {
        calc = null;
    }
}
```