# Migrating Junit4 tests to androidx: What causes 'delegate runner could not be loaded'?

Tags: android, junit, junit4, androidx

I am migrating my app to androidx, I can't seem to get my unit tests working. I took example from [Google's AndroidJunitRunnerSample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/tree/master/runner/AndroidJunitRunnerSample/), which has been updated to use the new androidx api. I get the following error when trying to run my tests:

```
java.lang.Exception: Delegate runner 'androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner' for AndroidJUnit4 could not be loaded. Check your build configuration.
```

Here is my module build.gradle:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}
dependencies {
    // Test dependencies
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.0.0-beta02'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.0.0-beta02'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-beta02'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-beta02'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.0.0"
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.room:room-testing:2.1.0-alpha01'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-beta02'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
}
```

And here is how my tests are structured:

```
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class EntityParcelTest {

    @BeforeClass
    public void createEntities() {
        // Setup...
    }

    @Test
    void someTest() {
        // Testing here
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please refer below post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55496047/delegate-runner-androidx-test-internal-runner-junit4-androidjunit4classrunner/64478059#64478059

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Removing `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)` annotations from the test classes fixed the issue, although I can't say why or how it fixed it.

Edit: All right I did some more testing. I migrated my app to Kotlin, and suddenly I noticed the tests began to work with the `@RunWith` annotation, too. Here's what I found out:

```
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class) // <-- @RunWith + @BeforeClass = Error
public class AndroidXJunitTestJava {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() {
        // Setting up once before all tests
    }

    @Test
    public void testing() {
        // Testing....
    }
}
```

This Java test fails with the `Delegate runner for AndroidJunit4 could not be loaded` error. But If I remove the `@RunWith` annotation, it works. Also, if I replace the `@BeforeClass` setup with just a `@Before`, like this:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class) // <-- @RunWith + @Before = works?
public class AndroidXJunitTestJava {

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        // Setting up before every test
    }

    @Test
    public void testing() {
        // Testing....
    }
}
```

The tests will run without errors. I needed to use the `@BeforeClass` annotation, so I just removed `@RunWith`.

But now that I am using Kotlin, the following (which should be equal to the first Java example) works:

```
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4
import org.junit.BeforeClass
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class AndroidXJunitTest {

    companion object {
        @BeforeClass fun setup() {
            // Setting up
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun testing() {
        // Testing...
    }

}
```

Also, as [Alessandro Biessek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52934007/10518087) said in an answer and @Ioane Sharvadze in the comments, the same error can happen with the `@Rule` annotation. If I add a line

```
 @Rule val instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
```

To the Kotlin example, the same delegate runner error happens. This must be replaced with

```
@get:Rule val instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
```

Explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29945087/kotlin-and-new-activitytestrule-the-rule-must-be-public#32827600).

Comment: But now, test is JUnit test.

Comment: For me the problem was that I'm using `@Rule` instead of `@get:Rule` annotation for `ActivityTestRule`. If you are using `Kotlin` then it might help you.

Comment: In Kotlin for me replacing `@Rule` by `@get:Rule` was sufficient. It works with `@Before`.

Comment: For me the solution was to change the method annotated with `@BeforeClass` to a `static` method as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/733042/2848676.  Seems like that may have helped with the original problem here as well.

Comment: Replacing ```@Rule``` with ```@get:Rule``` worked for me in kotlin. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks, removing the @RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class) worked. I usually like an explanation but do not seem to find one. Accoding to the documentation the annotation is required and should work https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner
I am speculating here but it just seems to be its some library/class incompatibility. Hopefully someone who has time can investigate, I will do if I find some. But for now this solution works, so up voting it.

Answer (score 52):

You also get the error message if you use a test rule in Kotlin and write it Java style

```
@Rule
var mainActivityActivityTestRule = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity::class.java)
```

You have to change `@Rule` to `@get:Rule`

```
@get:Rule
var mainActivityActivityTestRule = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity::class.java)
```

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: with @get: you are adding this annotation to underling java getter created for this field (which is method) instead of field itself

Comment: Good point. I prefer to use `@JvmField` instead of `@get:` annotation prefix as it generates the same bytecode that Java would with the originally mentioned syntax. I won't say it's a personal preference (as it does different things), but it's been error-proof in hundreds of tests so far and I do prefer it since I can verify that it's working.

Answer (score 11):

The error message displayed when I delete the @Test method.

You can try to put a @Test method and run

```
@Test
public void signInTest() {


}
```

Comment: Bizarrely this was the case for me. Once I added an empty function marked with `@Test` all was well

Answer (score 7):

While testing for activity make sure ActivityTestRule variable is public :

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<YourActivity> activityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(YourActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 ways that you can try to resolve this problem:

## Solution 1:

Build --> Clean Project. Then Build --> Rebuild Project

## Solution 2:

There are 2 packages that has of AndroidJUnit4

1. `androidx.test.runner` (deprecated)
2. `androidx.test.ext.junit.runners`

Make sure your build.gradle (app) has this line

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
    ....
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    ....
    }
}
```

and make sure you use (1) (which is deprecated) instead of (2) (new but not stable yet) in `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)` before your test class.

Comment: Took me around 2 hours to finally setup one single AndroidJUnitTest although following the official docs. As stated in this answer in my test class i changed the import:
USE: `import androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4` (although deprecated)
DON'T USE: `import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4`.
Not the perfect solution. But better to use a deprecated class instead of wasting more time just to get a single test running.
Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Changing

```
@Test
void someTest() {
    // Testing here
}
```

to

```
@Test
public void someTest() {
    // Testing here
}
```

works for me.

Answer (score 2):

The testing framework actually give too little information. I encountered the same issue and dug into the stack trace, and found these validation:

[image]

So **you must declare your `@BeforeClass` method `static`**.

Answer (score 2):

**AndroidJUnit4** DOESN'T SUPPORT in the functions with `@Test` annotations neither in the class nor in the superclass:

- the parameters: `@Test fun dontWork(param: String) {}`
- private access modifiers: `@Test private fun dontWork2() {}`

*Note: Without `@Test` annotations the above is allowed*

---

An expected way could be:

#### ClassTest.kt

```
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ClassTest : SuperTest() {

    @Test
    fun test() {}

    private fun allowedWithoutAnnotation(paramAllowed: String) {}

}
```

#### build.gradle (:mobile)

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}


dependencies {
    ...
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0'
}
```

GL

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that any class marked with the *@BeforeClass* annotation is *public static* . For example:

```
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class EntityParcelTest {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void createEntities() {
        // Setup...
    }

    @Test
    public void someTest() {
        // Testing here
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@JvmField`. From documentation

> Instructs the Kotlin compiler not to generate getters/setters for this property and expose it as a field

```
@Rule
@JvmField
val activityActivityTestRule = ActivityScenarioRule<MainActivity>(MainActivity::class.java)
```

Answer (score 1):

If after adding the following dependencies:

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 
           'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
```

and

```
android{
defaultConfig{
    ...
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    ...
   }
}
```

doesn't help then use the deprecated `AndroidJUnit4` class which belongs to the `androidx.test.runner` package instead of the one belongs to `androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4` package.

I still don't understand why `AndroidJUnit4` class is deprecated while the Gradle dependencies it belongs to is suggested by the Android team everywhere i.e [Codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-espresso-for-ui-testing/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Fandroid-training#2) and [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/espresso-testing)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I skipped annotate test case with `@Test`. It is not your case. This answer is for others like me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you haven't updated the runner on the gradle config file?

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Also, AndroidStudio 3.2 has an option to automate the migration of your dependencies to AndroidX (Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX...) that did that for me.

Comment: Seems I already have that testInstrumentationRunner set in my build.gradle, and I've also done the 'Migrate to AndroidX' refactor.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was the `@Rule` annotation..
I don't know the cause for now.

As a temporary workaround yo can for example start your activity using UIAutomator for ActivityTestRule.

Answer (score 0):

I gut this error for simply set fun as private, removing this solved this for me.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed with this configuration:

My dependencies:

```
/*Instrumentation Test*/
androidTestImplementation "org.assertj:assertj-core:3.12.2"
androidTestImplementation ('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0',{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0-rc01"
```

In my `defaultConfig` section I have:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "uy.edu.ude.archcomponents"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    testInstrumentationRunnerArguments clearPackageData: 'true'
}
```

In the test I have:

```
package uy.edu.ude.archcomponents.repository

import androidx.arch.core.executor.testing.InstantTaskExecutorRule
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry
import androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4
import com.example.android.roomwordssample.WordDao
import com.example.android.roomwordssample.WordRoomDatabase
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat
import org.junit.After
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import uy.edu.ude.archcomponents.entity.Word
import java.io.IOException


@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class WordDaoTest {

    @get:Rule
    val instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    private lateinit var wordDao: WordDao
    private lateinit var db: WordRoomDatabase

    @Before
    fun createDb() {
        val context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context
        // Using an in-memory database because the information stored here disappears when the
        // process is killed.
        db = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context, WordRoomDatabase::class.java)
                // Allowing main thread queries, just for testing.
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build()
        wordDao = db.wordDao()
    }

    @After
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun closeDb() {
        db.close()
    }

    @Test
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun insertAndGetWord() {
        runBlocking {
            val word = Word("word")
            wordDao.insert(word)
            val allWords = wordDao.getAlphabetizedWords().waitForValue()
            assertThat(allWords[0].word).isEqualTo(word.word)
        }
    }
}
```

I also use the android plugin version 3.4.2. I took the config from [here](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-room-with-a-view/tree/kotlin)

Answer (score 0):

Some other possible reasons:

- Having only `@SmallTest` (or Medium-/Large-) test methods. Marking at least one method  with `@Test` solves the issues.
- `setup()` / `teardown()` methods are not public.

Answer (score 0):

As for my case, defining a function parameter was the problem.

```
@Test
fun foo(string: String = "") {  // Causes "Delegate runner could not be loaded" error.
    // ...
}
```

I had to do something like the following.

```
@Test
fun foo() {
    foo("")
}

fun foo(string: String) {  // Can be called from other test functions.
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I fixed it by explicitly declaring all `@Test`, `@Before`, and `@After` methods as`public`, and declaring `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` as `public static`

If you leave any of those methods as implicitly/explicitly `protected`, or explicitly `private`; you'll encounter the following exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Delegate runner 'androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner' for AndroidJUnit4 could not be loaded.
```

So, the correct thing is to use

```
@Before
public void setUp() {

}

@BeforeClass
public static void init() {

}
```

Instead of:

```
@Before
void setUp() {

}

@Before
protected void setUp() {

}

@Before
private void setUp() {

}

@BeforeClass
public void init() {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

After spending lots of time in one minor problem in jetpack compose UI testing I found that the issue is in **composeTestRule** variable that was it is private so **Make sure that your composeTest variable should not be private.**

***@get:Rule
val composeTestRule = createAndroidComposeRule()***

NOT LIKE

***@get:Rule
private val composeTestRule = createAndroidComposeRule()***

Answer (score 0):

Another issue I was facing starting to using Espresso is the error

```
Failed to instantiate test runner class androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner site:stackoverflow.com
```

In this case I solved returning Unit to the fun

```
 fun Example() : Unit {your code}
```

Bye bye