# Attempted to use AndroidJUnit4 with standard JUnit runner and delegate runner 'org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner'could not be loaded

Tags: java, android, robolectric, android-espresso

I am using `espresso` to run some tests but I don't know why roboelectric is included in this error since the tests are for espresso only, below is the error :

```
java.lang.Exception: Attempted to use AndroidJUnit4 with standard JUnit runner and delegate runner 'org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner'could not be loaded. Check your build configuration.
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4.loadRunner(AndroidJUnit4.java:89)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4.loadRunner(AndroidJUnit4.java:63)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4.<init>(AndroidJUnit4.java:57)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidAnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AndroidAnnotatedBuilder.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.AndroidRunnerBuilder.runnerForClass(AndroidRunnerBuilder.java:153)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestLoader.doCreateRunner(TestLoader.java:73)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestLoader.getRunnersFor(TestLoader.java:104)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestRequestBuilder.build(TestRequestBuilder.java:789)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.buildRequest(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:543)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:386)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2145)
```

I followed the documentation for **espresso** and I see everything is fine. What could be the problem :

Below is my **gradle** file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'


jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.7.6.201602180812"
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    jacoco.includeNoLocationClasses = true
}

task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: ['testDebugUnitTest', 'createDebugCoverageReport']) {

    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }

    def fileFilter = ['**/R.class', '**/R$*.class', '**/BuildConfig.*', '**/Manifest*.*', '**/*Test*.*', 'android/**/*.*']
    def debugTree = fileTree(dir: "$project.buildDir/intermediates/classes/debug", excludes: fileFilter)
    def mainSrc = "$project.projectDir/src/main/java"

    sourceDirectories = files([mainSrc])
    classDirectories = files([debugTree])
    executionData = fileTree(dir: project.buildDir, includes: [
            'jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec', 'outputs/code-coverage/connected/*coverage.ec'
    ])
}


android {

    adbOptions {
        timeOutInMs 60 * 1000
    }

    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.levelapp.converge.convergelevelapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled true
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    testOptions {
        animationsDisabled true

        unitTests {
            includeAndroidResources = true
        }

        unitTests.all {
            jacoco {
                includeNoLocationClasses = true
            }
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    androidTestUtil 'com.android.support.test:orchestrator:1.0.2-alpha1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.7.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'


    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.0'


    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:1.0.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'multidex'
    }

}
```

Then below is the test am running:

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> activity = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

@Test
public void loadRecyclerview(){

    Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.rv)).
            perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(0, ViewActions.click()));

    Espresso.onView(withId(R.id.text))
            .check(matches(withText("k33too")))
            .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: @nilsi check my answer and see if that helps you.

Comment: Check the solution in the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61942438/5279996 GL

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I see you're using AndroidX.  Make sure you are using the correct import.  I ran in to this exact issue today and realized I was still using the old `import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;` when I should have been using `import androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;`

This fixed the the error for me.

Comment: androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4 is deprecated now.  What is now the correct thing to use?  androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4 from testImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'?

Comment: how should the gradle look life after @StephenM-onstrike- comment?

Answer (score 11):

I added the dependency to my gradle file and it can find Roboelectric now

```
    testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.0'
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 11):

update for kotlin. Make sure that all `@Rule` annotations are in form of `@get:Rule` - that was a problem in my case.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to Zac's answer I had to make use of the below dependency to solve this:

`import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4`

and in the app's build.gradle make sure you have this dependency:

`androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'`

and under the `android.buildConfig`, make sure you have:

`testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"`