# java.lang.RuntimeException: Delegate runner 'androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner' for AndroidJUnit4 could not be loaded

Tags: android

I'm using `androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner` as my `testInstrumentationRunner` from `androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'`.  Also, I annotated my test with `androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4` using the syntax `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)`

Suddenly I started getting the following error when I try to run `./gradlew connectedAndroidTest` across all device types and emulators that I could try.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Delegate runner 'androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner' for AndroidJUnit4 could not be loaded.
at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.throwInitializationError(AndroidJUnit4.java:92)
at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.loadRunner(AndroidJUnit4.java:82)
at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.loadRunner(AndroidJUnit4.java:51)
at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.<init>(AndroidJUnit4.java:46)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidAnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AndroidAnnotatedBuilder.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.AndroidRunnerBuilder.runnerForClass(AndroidRunnerBuilder.java:153)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestLoader.doCreateRunner(TestLoader.java:73)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestLoader.getRunnersFor(TestLoader.java:104)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestRequestBuilder.build(TestRequestBuilder.java:793)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.buildRequest(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:547)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:390)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2074)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.loadRunner(AndroidJUnit4.java:72)
... 17 more
Caused by: org.junit.runners.model.InitializationError
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:418)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:65)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.java:43)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.java:48)
... 20 more
```

A similar stack trace is in [Delegate runner 'androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner' for AndroidJUnit4 could not be loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55496047/delegate-runner-androidx-test-internal-runner-junit4-androidjunit4classrunner) but the author seems to be asking about converting Java to Kotlin, which is not relevant to my question.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the cause was I mistakenly introduced a parameter to one of the test methods.

To fix the problem, I changed from this:

```
@Test
public void testTapReservationButton(List<String> settings) throws Exception {
    //...
}
```

To this:

```
@Test
public void testTapReservationButton() throws Exception {
    //...
}
```

The change was the removal of `List<String> settings` from the parameters list.  It was a typo that I even added that, it a result of bad search and replace logic.  Unfortunately the error is not helpful at all.

Note `@Test` is `org.junit.Test`